# Should I consider x0, threshold when using a Tensorflow placeholder function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently doing a mood classification project by supervised learning, using tensor flow.

And in machine learning theory, as you know, there is always an x0 which is +1. When making a placeholder for input dataset, is the function automatically produce a x0 part? or should I designate it manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of thinking about `x0`. Either your input has an extra dimension, which always has `1` in it, and then a linear regression or a fully connected layer in a neural network will be represented as:

```
out = W * in
```

where `*` is matrix-vector multiplication, or, which is more common, to not add that extra dimension, and instead model it as

```
out = W * in + b
```

This is, in part, to highlight the difference between `W`, which is how we "weight" the input, and `b`, which is how much we "shift" it (`b` is called a "bias" term). One other reason why this representation is more desirable is because it is common to regularize `W`, but not `b`.

Now, back to your question, TensorFlow neural network library models fully connected layer in terms of a weight matrix and a bias vector, therefore you do not need to add an extra one to your input vector.

If you use low-level Tensor operations instead of the high-level predefined layers, then TensorFlow makes no assumptions about your input, and if you want to model your model in terms of operations on a vector with an extra `1` in it, it is your responsibility to add that `1` to that vector, TensorFlow will not do that for you.